Content Resolver LIMIT Error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid token LIMIT
I am pulling all the videos from the gallery and I want to add a limit in the query but this is the error I get: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid token LIMIT

        val filter = when (filterStatus) {
            "date asc" -> "${MediaStore.Video.Media.DATE_ADDED} ASC"
            "date desc" -> "${MediaStore.Video.Media.DATE_ADDED} DESC"
            "duration asc" -> "${MediaStore.Video.Media.DURATION} ASC"
            "duration desc" -> "${MediaStore.Video.Media.DURATION} DESC"
            "name asc" -> "${MediaStore.Video.Media.DISPLAY_NAME} ASC"
            "name desc" -> "${MediaStore.Video.Media.DISPLAY_NAME} DESC"
            else -> null
        }

        val cursor = contentResolver.query(
            MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
            projection,
            null,
            null,
            filter + " LIMIT 20"
        )

It says LIMIT is invalid, but shouldn't it normally be like this?

Print the generated SQL to see what you have. My guess is you're missing some "order by" or such.
